# Can I update data in Essbase using Excel add-In/smart view

Tags: essbase

Can i insert new data/update the existing data into Essbase using Excel add-In/Smart view like I update the data into Palo Multidimentional database?

regards,
Sri.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is what Lock & Send is used for. After you have drilled to an intersection that you would to update/load/change data in, you enter it directly in within Excel. Then perform a Lock operation using the add-in or SmartView. This tells Essbase that you would like to update data that is currently being shown on your spreadsheet. Then perform a Send operation. This will upload all of the data on your sheet back to the database, assuming that you have access to change that data (if you are a read-only user or don't have sufficient filter access, for example, then you can't change the data). Note that all of the data in the spreadsheet will be sent up -- so it is useful to navigate to the smallest possible subset of data that you would like to change.

After sending the data, it will automatically be unlocked. Then just retrieve the sheet to verify that the data you uploaded did in fact upload. If you are trying to upload to members that are dynamic calc, for example, then it won't work. Also note that typically data is loaded such that every intersection point is a Level-0 member, if not then it is possible that a subsequent aggregation/calc in the database might erase the data you just uploaded.